# How to solve "Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request."?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm a beginner, trying to develop a windows service that sends emails before the expiration date of an insurance policy. I set the service for auto start, yet it doesn't appear to start automatically (seen on Services console). And when I start it manually, it does send the alerts but stops with error 1064, which after checking the event viewer is caused by other instance of the service, already running. Yet, if I don't attempt to start the service manually no alerts are sent.

I tried to uninstall the service using installutil and reinstall it, to assure there's only a single instance running.

```
//According to event viewer this is the block of code where the issue occurs.
  ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
        // Iterating each service to check that if a service named
        // EmailExpiracaoSeguroAuto is found then check that its status whether
        // it is running or stopped. If found running then it will
        // stop that service; else it starts that service
        foreach (ServiceController x in services)
        {
            if (x.DisplayName == "EmailExpiracaoSeguroAuto")
            {
                if (x.Status == System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    x.Stop();
                }
                else
                {
               //More precisely HERE     
                    x.Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My expectation is being able to overcome this error, having the service starting automatically and keep it running.